# Breaking down the ring middleware scenario

Tags: clojure, middleware, ring

Ring is super sleek and has some pretty sensible defaults for middleware(s).

When I made a new app through leiningen (lein) I ended up with something like this in my router/handler

```
(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-defaults

Now I want to add more middleware (cemerick/friend) so I can do things like authentication for logins.

So, how would I translate the above into something more reminiscent of the ring middleware "stack," like at the bottom of the page https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-defaults/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/defaults.clj

```
(def app
  (-> handler  
    (wrap-anti-forgery)
    (wrap-flash)
    (wrap-session)
    (wrap-keyword-params)
    (wrap-resource)
    (wrap wrap-file)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because ring just uses function composition for middleware you can simply wrap friend around the call to wrap defaults:

```
(def app 
  (my-additional-middleware 
    (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults)
  arguments to my additional middleware))
```

or you can thread it (for instance when you have several middlewares):

```
(def app
  (-> (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults)
      (friend-stuff arg arg)
      (other-middleware arg arg arg))
```

Getting the order of the middleware right is still up to you :-/